# How to check checkboxes in caml query?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, caml

In SharePoint 2010 client object model (JavaScript), I am using this caml query to download list items.

There is a column called `'Office'` and in it, there are several check boxes (i.e. its a multi-select field). I am looking to get the items where the checkbox in the `Office` field, that has the name `'Toronto'` is checked. I don't want to consider the values of the other checkboxes in the `Office` field. This query below is not working though because I am getting 0 items, when I know I should be getting more.

```
var camlquerystring = "
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Office'/>
<Value Type='Boolean'>
Toronto
</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
</View>";
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:

Change `<Value Type='Boolean'>` to `<Value Type='Text'>` or `<Value Type='MultiChoice'>`.

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/b20b1945-4b73-4320-8666-957650dc6a20